# Removing the first entry of each subset using ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I have a dataframe with the headings "id" and "date", where each id can have multiple dates. For example:

```
id    date
001   03/05/2000
001   06/05/2001
001   01/09/2002
002   03/05/2000
002   03/09/2004
003   03/05/2000
003   03/07/2001
003   02/10/2002
```

I want to remove the row of the first entry (ordered by date). So for the above example I would want to end up with:

```
id    date
001   06/05/2001
001   01/09/2002
002   03/09/2004
003   03/07/2001
003   02/10/2002
```

I've tried things along the lines of:

```
reduced <- ddply(data, .(id), function(x) x[-1,])
```

with no luck.

Any ideas how I could do this efficiently?

The problem is breaking it up into subsets based on the id, removing the first row (ordered by date) and then rejoining them into a final data frame, which is what ddply is usually good for but I can't seem to make it work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr:`

```
dat1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  do(tail(.,-1))
```

Using `BaseR`, Assuming I have an ordered data:

```
dat1[duplicated(dat1$id,fromLast = F),]
```

Using `data.table`:

```
 setDT(dat1)[,tail(.SD,-1),by="id"]
```

Regarding the efficiency part , I ran a microbenchmark on four queries along with OP's query of ddply. Below is the outcome for running for = 10000. It seems BaseR duplicated is little ahead for the queries I wrote in the manner I wrote. It may subject to change in case there are another ways of writing these queries which can be more efficient, May be someone can guide me to that. Thanks

```
Unit: microseconds
                                      expr      min
   setDT(dat1)[, tail(.SD, -1), by = "id"] 1458.790
 dat1[duplicated(dat1$id, fromLast = F), ]  170.227
 dat1 %>% group_by(id) %>% do(tail(., -1)) 2014.897
   ddply(dat1, .(id), function(x) x[-1, ]) 1667.238
       lq      mean   median       uq        max neval
 1644.247 1788.5900 1715.314 1805.304  24960.212 10000
  230.614  263.3895  251.405  277.276   4469.816 10000
 2237.728 2490.9345 2329.737 2480.637 213565.874 10000
 1845.771 2027.1384 1910.950 2003.320 237116.650 10000
```

Output:

```
     id      date
  <int>     <chr>
1     1 06-May-01
2     1 01-Sep-02
3     2 03-Sep-04
4     3 03-Jul-01
5     3 02-Oct-02
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain If there is a mistake I would either correct it or delete it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(id) %>% slice(-1)

     id       date
  <chr>      <chr>
1   001 06/05/2001
2   001 01/09/2002
3   002 03/09/2004
4   003 03/07/2001
5   003 02/10/2002
```

`slice(-1)` removes the first row for each group.

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- data[order(data$date),]
data <- data[ duplicated(data$id),]
```